# SQL Table Join Unique field named different

Tags: sql-server, join

Been working on this for a few hours and its driving me nuts. Normally I just need to do simple MS SQL stuff from one table but now I need data from 2 and am lost.

**Database name:** Event
**Table names:** FeedUpdate and Fixture

**Feed Update Fields:**
[EventId] ,[Description] ,[DataProviderId] ,[UpdateTimestamp]

**Fixture Fields:**
[FixtureId],[Description] ,[DataProviderId] ,[StartTime]

**The query I have been trying so far:**

```
SELECT [FixtureId],[Description] ,[DataProviderId] ,[StartTime]
FROM [Event].[dbo].[Fixture]
WHERE [DataProviderId] = '6' AND StartTime >= '2013-03-05 00:00:00.0000000'
  AND StartTime <= '2013-03-05 00:30:00.0000000'

  UNION ALL

SELECT [EventId] ,[Description] ,[DataProviderId] ,[UpdateTimestamp]
FROM [Event].[dbo].[FeedUpdate]
WHERE [DataProviderId] = '6' AND UpdateTimestamp
  BETWEEN '2013-03-05 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2013-03-05 00:01:00.0000000'
```

I wish to have this information in one table view, grouped by FixtureId/EventId as these are both the same, just carrying a different name. I'd also like just one row per FixtureId/EventId, as the "FeedUpdate" table has multiple entries for the same EventId

Any pointers would be great

Comment: provide some sample data, that will help to create accurate sql as per your need.

Comment: all the values in other fields are same across the rows for a single EventId or they may have different values.

Answer (score 0):

Your column names need to match - you have two different, one EventId and the other FixtureId.

Use AS to assign the same column name:

```
[FixtureId] AS [FieldId]
...
[EventId] AS [FieldId]
```

Also, your date fields don't match.

Comment: EventId and the other FixtureId have the exact same values. Just different name. How can I get around that/

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what you want as a result when you have more than one row with the same id, so I'm guessing at the 'latest' information. 
Also, you operate with two different dateranges. I'm just ignoring that for now, but i think they should probably be the same range.

Possible solutions:
1)
Make a union like you do today, but use 'as' to make sure the output from both statements have the same field names.

Then from that union select the entry for each 'id' that has the maximum timestamp.

2)
You might be able to improve on this by using a couple of Common Table Expressions, the first one listing the latest of each update, the second listing the entries not already returned in the update and finally a select on the output from these two CTEs ordered by event id or timestamp.

3)
OR, you could solve this with temporary tables and updates.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @events table (
    EventId int primary key,
    Description varchar(max),
    DataProviderId int,
    [timestamp] datetime
)
INSERT @events (EventId, Description, DataProviderId, [Timestamp])
  SELECT [FixtureId], [Description], [DataProviderId], [StartTime]
    FROM [Event].[dbo].[Fixture]
      WHERE [DataProviderId] = '6' AND StartTime >= '2013-03-05 00:00:00.0000000'
        AND StartTime <= '2013-03-05 00:30:00.0000000'

UPDATE @events
SET [Description]=u.[Description], 
    [DataProviderId]=u.[DataProviderId], [Timestamp]=u.[UpdateTimestamp]
  FROM @events e
    inner join [Event].[dbo].[FeedUpdate] u on e.EventId = u.EventId
      where u.[DataProviderId] = '6' AND u.UpdateTimestamp
      BETWEEN '2013-03-05 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2013-03-05 00:01:00.0000000'
```

Comment: This did the job:SELECT F.*
  FROM [Event].[dbo].[Fixture] As F
  Where F.DataProviderId=6 AND F.StartTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-03-05 00:00:00') AND F.StartTime <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-03-05 00:30:00') AND F.FixtureId in(
  SELECT EventId FROM [Event].[dbo].FeedUpdate)
  Order By StartTime asc
GO

Comment: Joe, that will return only the events that where already in Fixture, so why the join with FeedUpdate?